# How to handle back button using view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, back-stack

I am having two fragments Frag A and Frag B which are rendered using view pager . 
If user has swiped  from A to B then presses back button(when in B) then user should go to A instead of coming out of view pager . How can we achieve this ?

Adding transaction to backstack does not seem to help .

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to override the `onKeyDown()` method in the `Activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        return true;
    } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

This will capture the "back" button press event and send the user to the first item in the ViewPager.

There is also [ViewPager#getCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29) which can be used to go back only if the user swiped.  An implementation like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        return true;
    } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

would send the user back to the previous page only if the user was on the next page. Else, it will register the "back" normally and the user will exit as expected.

You may want the case in which the user goes back to the previous page (assuming you have more than two pages). In which case, you want to implement the [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and save the position every time `onPageSelected(int position)` is called.  If you implement them in a stack, then you can pop them off every time the user presses "back".  Once the stack is empty, exit the app.

**EDIT**

As correctly stated in the comments by Jade Byfield, a slightly easier way to do this would be to use `onBackPressed()` in the Activity.  This will only work in API levels 5+.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(i_dont_want_to_leave) {
     myViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed(); // This will pop the Activity from the stack.
  }
}
```

Comment: Could he also override onBackPressed? Or is that only for earlier APIs?

Comment: Using onKeyDown() works on every platform API level 1+.  Also, unless I've been using it wrong all along, onBackPressed won't prevent the Activity from being popped from the stack.  If you return `true` in `onKeyDown()`, then that will be the only thing that happens and the event will stop cascading.

Comment: Wait.  Just had a brain dump.

Yes.  He can use onBackPressed() if he wants to target API 5+.  Just don't call the `super.onBackPressed()` unless you're absolutely sure you want to exit.

Answer (score 4):

On the Android Docs page

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager

I found an example of handling `ViewPager` sliding and there's a method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
  else {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
  }
}
```

This selects a previous page or exits the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to delegate the back key handling to the respective fragments. I have used a CustomFragment which supports a method to handle the back key. All the Fragments will be extending from this CustomFragment.

```
public abstract class BackKeyHandlingFragment extends Fragment {
    public abstract boolean handleBackKey();
}
```

Activity can delegate the backKey processing to current Fragment. Fragments can perform required actions in their respective implementation of handleBackKey method. The method can return true to tell activity not to process the back key. To go ahead with default back key action at Activity level, the method can return false.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
     BackKeyHandlingFragment fragment = (BackKeyHandlingFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
     // Fragment should return boolean according to app requirements after processing back key
     if (!fragment.handleBackKey()) { 
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```