# getHeight and getWidth for Custom View returning 0

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, activity-lifecycle

I have a custom `View` to represent an ImageView with a parallax effect, adapted from the one found in the answer to this SO question: [How to have a wider image scrolling in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207612/how-to-have-a-wider-image-scrolling-in-the-background).

The `View` has a `setBackgroundDrawable()` method to set its background image that does some calculations to know the size that the bitmap should have in order to be wide enough to be scrolled with a parallax effect, if cropping is needed to keep the aspect ratio, etc.

I'm getting an "`IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`" in

```
(...)

int width = this.getWidth();
int height = this.getHeight();

Bitmap mCurrentBackground=Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (width*FACTOR), height, Config.ARGB_8888);

(...)
```

because `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are returning zero.

I understand that this is happening because the View doesn't know its own size yet when I call the said function, for example, in an Activity's `onCreate` method. Same thing happens if I try to set the background in `onStart` or `onResume`...

I've managed to set the background if I call the function in `onWindowFocusChanged()`, but I still get the error sometimes (e.g. if I switch the screen orientation when an `EditText` is focused).

Is there a way to get around this? Any kind of callback or phase in the lifecycle where the whole View was created (like the onViewCreated from the Fragment class)? I can only call my custom View's `setBackgroundDrawable` after the View has been assigned a height and a width.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried adding a `GlobalLayoutListener` to the View's `ViewTreeObserver`:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = parallaxBackground.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    ...

        parallaxBackground.setBackgroundDrawable(d1);

            ViewTreeObserver obs = parallaxBackground.getViewTreeObserver();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }

    });
```

but it results in the same behavior I get from setting the background in the `onWindowFocusChanged()` method. I.e. the `gedtWidth()`/`getHeight()` return zero inside the listener's `onGlobalLayout` if I switch the phone's orientation when an `EditText` is selected.

**EDIT 2:**

It probably has something to do with the keyboard as I observed some behavior like the height being calculated taking the keyboard's existence into account.

Deleting:

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
```

from my `onGlobalLayout` shown in the first EDIT seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure in your case, but I've used this some time ago. Simply use a `ViewObserver`. In my case I've used something like this:

```
final ViewTreeObserver treeObs = dataView.getViewTreeObserver();

treeObs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // This will be called when the layout is finished, just before displaying
    ...
  }
}
```